The same parameters considered in both fixed and random effects?
I'm am trying to use the glmmTMB() function from the l R package to specify a random effects structure.
In my experiment, I sampled at five sites over different periods to explore the relationship between the concentration and different environmental factors. In these environmental factors, water quality such as pH, turbidity, EC are always different, but distance of sampling site to the field is always the same.
I have set up my command as follows in R:
library(glmmTMB)
model<-glmmTMB(concentration ~ turbidity + distance + EC + pH +
               (1|site),data = data,family = gaussian)

While each site was included in the random effect, distances was included in the fixed effect. However, since these distances are unique values for each site.They are conceptually the same parameters in both fixed and random effects.
Does this lead to incorrect fitting results?

Welcome to Cross Validated.
From the study description, it appears that distance is a site-level variables, that is, it only changes between sites, and not within sites, whereas the other fixed effects

Does this lead to incorrect fitting results?

No, it's perfectly valid to have a "between" site variable in your model, and this should not cause any problem fitting the model.
One thing that you should consider though, is whether any of the fixed effects are mediators. If so, then you wouldn't normally want to include them. Only include a variable as a fixed effect if 1) it is a variable you specifically want to model the association of, with the outcome, or 2) you think it is a potential confounder, or 3) it is associated with the outcome (but is not a cause - or a proxy of a cause - of one of the other fixed effects).

As long as distance is a numeric variable rather than a categorical variable ...

Thans a lot for your answer. Does it mean that although the values of turbidity, pH, and EC different between each sample, distance varies between different sites, while samples within the same site have the same distance, a model with site as a random effect and distance as a fixed effect would still be feasible? Will there be any other issues arising due to the overlap between the fixed effect distance and the random effect site during model fitting?

I'm not completely sure what your concern is, but there should not be a problem.
